# Multi-user security in Android system services

Tags: android, security, android-source, android-security

**ActivityManagerService** defends some of its APIs using system permissions, and sometimes calling `handleIncomingUser()` in order to verify that no app affects another user's app behavior.

However, some of those APIs are not protected, such as: `startActivityAsCaller()`, `notifyActivityDrawn()` and others that use an `IBinder token` in order to identify the affected app (but no comparison is then made between the calling app's uid and the activity this token belongs to). Can't another app/user forge this token?

**Some APIs don't even have this "token" security!**

Such is the `setTaskResizeable()` where all it takes is that user B knows a task number assigned to a user A's task, and he/she can call this API for a task that doesn't belong to them.
Why is this not checked for calling uid? Am I missing something?

EDIT: I know that Binder tokens are supposedly protected, I just don't understand how. All they represent is a memory address. But even if they are,  the second question remains, how are APIs such as `setTaskResizeable()` which may affect another user's task, protected?

Comment: for a `Binder` "token": no, it cannot be forged

Comment: When it comes down to it a binder token is simply a native pointer to something. In other words an int/long. I agree that it's hard to "know" the actual integer, but it's not impossible.

Comment: and this is how it works: http://pastebin.com/tg1cSC3P, see the comment at the bottom

Comment: Thanks. I've used Binder tokens in the past, and I understand how they basically work, but I am not sure whether they are secure enough for identifying a user. On top of that, as I mentioned, some APIs don't use tokens, just taskId or stackId, and my question i: how is this considered secure?

Comment: i have no idea, i can only say that Binder tokens are secure and you cannot forge them, here you can find more info on that: https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/6/25/3 - the author is (among others) the `Binder` creator